# IIS Express URL binding is not bound as configured?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, configuration, iis-express

I have 2 bindings for my app configured in the `applicationhost.config` like this:

```
<bindings>
     <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:12692:localhost" />
     <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:127.0.0.2" />
</bindings>
```

As you can see there is one IP binding there, at first there is no ACL setup to allow it so I have to run the VS as admin so that the binding can be done OK (otherwise the app won't run). If I run it as admin I can see the 2 bindings configured OK (they are shown in the IIS Express window accessible from the system tray icon).
Now I want it more convenient (not requiring administrative privilege) by adding the IP (for the second binding) to the ACL by using `netsh` like this:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://127.0.0.2:80/ user=everyone
```

It reported OK, then I could try reopening the project normally (not as admin) and the app run OK (not any binding error reported) but I could see just one binding (the second binding), the first binding is not configured as expected. Now if I try running the VS as admin again, it still works fine with 2 bindings configured correctly.

So looks like it's just a problem of running VS as admin or not (the ACL configuration is not involved). How could that cause the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not a recommended way to modify the applicationhost.config file. another thing is when you open a visual studio you can only see the one site bing in the application property. if you want to use more than two bindings with a site you could use the iis or iisexpress command:

run command prompt as administrator.

enter the iisexpress.exe folder path by running below command:

```
cd C:\Program Files\IIS Express
```

then run below command to run iisexpress site:

```
iisexpress /config:C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\webformtest1\.vs\webformtest1\config\applicationhost.config /site:webformtest1(3)
```

in this way you can see both the binding in iis express tray:

[image]

Comment: So each time I debug my app, I have to run the cmd as admin like this? It's even more inconvenient than running VS as admin (because of no typing at all)

Comment: @Hopeless could you please share which applicationhist.config you are modifying?

Comment: my `applicationhost.config` is at path `.vs\config` in which `.vs` is in the same parent folder with my app folder. There is not any config file under the path you configure for IIS Express on my computer (there is not any `Administrator` folder but just my specific account folder which has administrative privilege however still no config file found down the path).

Comment: @Hopeless as suggested directly modify the applicationhost.config file is not a recommended way. use visual studio to make changes in the site.

Comment: how could you achieve what I want (2 bindings for an app) using VS? It may not be the recommended way but may be the only way when we need to handle some cases that VS does not support. I also wonder why the project Properties does not allow us to add more bindings right via the UI, there is only 1 slot for 1 binding which usually suites almost the cases.

Comment: @Hopeless then you have to run the project as mentioned by using cmd or host site in iis. this is the only way. and this behavior is by design in visual studio. I hope you understand.

Comment: OK if running the CMD **without admin privilege**, then I accept your answer. But if still we need to run it as admin then I don't have to do that. Why? Because running VS directly as admin **works fine**, the 2 bindings are bound OK. I just want it to work OK **without having to run anything as admin**. Thanks for your answer anyway. Also what said here were all mentioned clearly in my question.

Comment: @Hopeless you could run cmd without admin privilege and run this command.

Comment: OK let me check it again, anyway it's still inconvenient, really I wish that we could run VS normally and still have 2 bindings working.

Comment: @Hopeless the above test snapshot is without running cmd as administrator.